# Prism XF: issue with creating 'child' view-models

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I can see in the source code of Prism this

```cs
Container.RegisterType<INavigationService, UnityPageNavigationService>(_navigationServiceName);
```

Why is it using a specific name? Why not have this:

```cs
Container.RegisterType<INavigationService, UnityPageNavigationService>();
```

I am asking because I'm having a hard time with child view-models:

```cs
class ItemViewModel : BindableBase
{
   public ItemViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
   {
   }
}
```

and I'm creating items on a page:

```cs
class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

    public MainPageViewModel(Funct<ItemViewModel> itemFactory)
    {
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters) {
         Items = ...  // Create items, where each item is created using itemFactory
    }
}
```

But the DI fails, it throws exception because it cannot create `ItemViewModel`:

> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type = "MyApp.ViewModels.ItemViewModel", name =
>   "(none)".
>       Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>       Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, Prism.Navigation.INavigationService, is an interface and cannot be
>   constructed.

Are you missing a type mapping?

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Forms navigation is based on the page being Navigated from. As such the Prism Forms PageNavigationService must be aware of the page which is associated with that particular instance of the service. In order to facilitate this, we register the service with a "secret" key, and then resolve the service and pass it in using the named instance "navigationService" for the ViewModel to consume.

You should not be using the NavigationService outside of the context of a ViewModel unless of course you are performing an absolute navigation (resetting Application.MainPage).

Note that each DI Container handles this a little differently, and each one uses a slight variation of the registration key, all of which is easy enough to look up with Prism being Open Source.

Comment: Thanks! I am not using the NavigationService outside of the view-model. The `ItemViewModel` is a view-model. It's not the view-model of a Page, if this what you're referring to. Do you have any solution for my scenario? I don't think my scenario is special.

Comment: It’s currently being considered. But unless Xamarin can give us a way to get the parent Page of the View there’s nothing we can do to support it.

Comment: But in my case it has nothing to do with a view. I am creating a child view-model where I need DI to navigationService to work.

Comment: The obvious solution is to pass the `INavigationService` from the view-model of the page to the item view-model. But I am looking to see if there isn't any other nicer solution.

Comment: Found an ugly workaround which will still uses DI. Please share some thoughts on this...

Comment: As I understand your use case, you're essentially creating a View (custom control) with it's own ViewModel and that View is not a Page. That scenario as I mentioned is under investigation, but not currently supported. Any scenario that would work would effectively be a hack at the moment.

Comment: That's not correct, please read again, the view-model `MainPageViewModel` as its name suggests is a view-model of a `Page`. This view-model creates and exposes view-model instances of `ItemViewModel`.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and make guess that the whole reason you want to do this is that you have something like a ListView and inside of the ViewCell you have a button or ContextAction that needs a binding to the command but you cannot do that be a basic Model/DTO isn't meant to handle that... If this is the case you're approaching this all wrong, as you need to simply update the Binding to work with a command in your actual ViewModel

Comment: I see what you mean but it's not that. You've never had to create separate child view-models?

Comment: I've made "ViewModels" that take multiple DTO's and expose them so that ModelA and ModelB can both be used in the context of something like a ViewCell, while also providing computed properties from those models... But I would say that if you're getting into the realm of needing to resolve special services and particularly the NavigationService you're making it far more difficult than it needs to be.